# Check if a string match a defined pattern

Tags: java, char, digit, letter

I am working on an assignment right now where I have to enter an input in "ABC123456" format entry and see if it is valid or not. I don't understand how to check each character if it is a number or letter. Here is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class NetID {


    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        String userInput, char0thru2, char3thru8, uppercase, netID;

        System.out.println("Please enter the NetID to verify:");
        userInput = input.nextLine();

        if (userInput.length() != 9) {
            System.out.println("Your NetID needs to be 9 characters long, it needs to be in this format: ABC123456");
        }   
        if (userInput.length() == 9){
            char0thru2 = userInput.substring(0, 3);
            char3thru8 = userInput.substring(3, 9);
            uppercase = char0thru2.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter-char-, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit-char-

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a pattern:

```
String userInput = "ABC133456";

    if(!Pattern.matches("[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{6}", userInput))
         System.out.println("Your NetID needs to be 9 characters long, it needs to be in this format: ABC123456");
    else
         System.out.println("Ok!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way

Loop over the input string, and get each character at the counter position of the loop , then compare the ASCCI values of each character. If u want first 3 character as letters then till the counter is 2 compare them with ASCCI value of A-Z and all other with ASCCI value of 0-9

You can try below code , may have some compilation errors as I haven't compiled it :(

```
  if(userInput.length==9)
   {
     for (int i =0;i<userInput.lenght;i ++){
       if (i <3){
        if(!(userInput.charAt(i)<91      &&userInput.charAt(i)>64)){
         System.out.println("invalid string");
          break;
        }
      }
      if (i >2){
      if(!(userInput.charAt(i)<58 &&userInput.charAt(i)>47)){
       System.out.println("invalid string");
        break;
      }
     }
    }
   }
```

Comment: I have only recently started to learn coding and I am not really sure I understand what you mean

Comment: U have a constant format to get string ? i.e first 3 letters always be letter and last 3 always be number ? And string will be of length 9 ?

Comment: Yes the first three are letters and last 6 are numbers and length is 9

Comment: Added a code ,please try to remove compilation errors if any and try to execute it will work

Answer (score 0):

Simply iterate over String and use isDigit() of Character class,sample code below, hope it helps:

```
String inp="qwerty43";
for(int i=0;i< myStr.length();i++){
       if (Character.isDigit(myStr.charAt(i))) {
            System.out.println("Digit Found");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Letter Found");
        }
}
```